# Error when install MySQL 5.5 on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, installation

When i install Mysql installer community 5.5.62.0, I Got message:
"Internal Error. (Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for mor information.) The installer will now close"

I try to install another version like 5.7.25.0 and 5.7.27.0 but it's not working too.

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I Got this solution, the solution is move your installer from local disk c. just it. :D